# error when trying to get the azure access token in my app

Tags: java, azure-active-directory

I have this error when i try to get access token from azure in master user authentication type.
Can someone help me understanding this problem?
when i debug the error is linked to this code:

```
// Get access token
    String accessToken;
    try {
        accessToken = AzureADService.getAccessToken();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        // Log error message
        // logger.error(ex.getMessage());

        return "ko";// ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex.getMessage());

    }
```

Exception:

> No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.InstanceDiscoveryMetadataEntry]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

My AzureADService class is from this project:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/Java/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/PowerBIEmbedding/src/main

Comment: Could you share more details about AzureADService class?

Comment: I don't know if it's a dependencies probleme (maven) or  not because i can run it in another project and it works but when i integrate the code in my application project i have this error.
i updated the project, i also checked "download artifact source" in maven properties

Comment: Please add the full stack trace!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the code in AzureADService.java. It works well.

[image]

The flow that the code use is [Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc). You could see the limits in the **Important**. Please check your account if it is appropriate. If not, you could use [Integrated Windows Auth Flow](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/tree/master/Integrated-Windows-Auth-Flow).

> 1. The Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. This means that you must use
>    a tenant-specific endpoint
>    ([https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenantId_or_Name%7D)) or the
>    organizations endpoint.
> 2. Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use ROPC.
> 3. Accounts that don't have passwords can't sign in through ROPC. For this scenario, we recommend that you use a different flow for your app
>    instead.
> 4. If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.
> 5. ROPC is not supported in hybrid identity federation scenarios (for example, Azure AD and ADFS used to authenticate on-premises accounts).
>    If users are full-page redirected to an on-premises identity
>    providers, Azure AD is not able to test the username and password
>    against that identity provider. Pass-through authentication is
>    supported with ROPC, however.

Comment: I think my account is appropriate because in a local project it works fine but when i integrate it in our organization's application it doesn't work with the same account.
Can someone explain the error i get because it can help me to find a solution.
is it a maven dependencies problem or a network security problem because i run it from our organisatiion network?

Comment: I can't see what you are talking about.
I dont find any flow in my code (ROPC or IWAF).
Can you please explain this. i cant see the class whith the function getAcessToken to debug it.
is it a msal4j.jar problem (dependencies?)

Comment: I m in a company vpn?
can the security strategy create this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find the point error in your stack trace, and I don't know which line the error appears. ROPC flow is the flow uses [username/password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#usernamepassword) to access.

Comment: hello my problem was linked to maven dependecies.
i was necessary to use https to get it 
i found a topic talking about a setting file to put in the .m2 repertory and it works.